# Inserting dependent records into multiple tables once?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a form that take input in multiple fields.

However in view it looks likes that they all are grouped together but in Database they all belong to different tables and they all in dependent over each other, problem is how to insert the record in multiple tables referencing each other such that, `Table 2` requires the *Primary Key* from the data entered in `Table 1` to insert the record in it.

Current I am doing this in the following manner:

```
-- Running an insert query
INSERT INTO table1(...) VALUES(…);
--Reading the parimry key from the last query
SELECT subId from table1 sub WHERE sub.peId=@pEquipment AND sub.shId=@sh AND sub.subName=@sEquipment AND sub.make=@make AND sub.model=@model AND sub.serialNo=@serial;
--Inserting in the second table
INSERT INTO table2(subId,table2) VALUES(…);
--Reading primary key from the second table
SELECT table2Id FROM table2 p WHERE p.subId=@subId,p.table2=@table2;
-- Insert in the third table
INSERT INTO table3(table2Id,table3,table3Desc) VALUES(…);
```

However this is not the right way i believe? A lot of back and forth connection opening and closing, reading writing plus if a query failed in the middle than the schema will be in an inconsistent state?

- Is there a way i can insert multiple records within one query?
- Or what else approach should i use here?

Comment: All of the above is server side code that can be wrapped around 1 transaction with 1 open and 1 close. Why not? Where does the "back and forth connection" come from?

Comment: from `back and forth connection` i actually wanted to say a lot of read & write operating not opening or closing connections, sorry if i didnt said it well. And how can i do it one transatioc?

Comment: By default, if you open a connection, do processing and close the connection, all the processing would belong to a transaction. You could control this in detail as in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818751%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure and insert it all in one transaction and one call. Also, you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the identity value that was inserted in the previous command:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Name (... parameter list ...)

AS

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO table1(...) VALUES(…);

INSERT INTO table2(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),table2) VALUES(…);

INSERT INTO table3(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),table3,table3Desc) VALUES(…);

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: can i use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` while passing commands from code and not using SP?

Comment: Only if you don't use stored proc but use just text commands. Otherwise it won't return you the right value as stored procs have their own scope.